# Univariate odds ratio calculation - by hand versus log regression

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, odds-ratio

If I have only **one binary predictor variable** for a binary outcome, is there any meaningful difference between doing hand calculation of odds ratio (OR = ad/bc), versus doing a univariate logistic regression and exponentiating the coefficient? The values I get are virtually the same after a 4-5 decimal points, plus the 95% CI. I'm sure if I do the regression calculation by hand, I can show mathematically why. Is there a convention for one approach over another in publication?

One advantage I can see with hand calculation is that someone reading my summary data can re-do the calculation themselves with just a calculator to verify the findings, without needing my full dataset or programming. It is also easier for someone with no statistical background (which is the majority of journal readership) to follow, rather than a regression, which I find, to a non-stats audience, is like black magic - the regression spits out a useful number that they must believe in, but they don't know/can't see/don't understand how the number was produced.